# Postfix and Dovecot I can not send external emails

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I am trying to install an email server with dovecot and postfix using a MySQL database.
I can send emails to other users of my domain @ eddelus.com and I can also receive emails from external domains, but I can not send emails to external domains.

I can connect using telnet to ports 110 and 587

Looking at the log (cat /var/log/mail.log) I find this:

```
Jul 23 15:47:55 eddelus postfix/submission/smtpd[4171]: connect from unknown[90.164.39.14]
Jul 23 15:47:56 eddelus postfix/submission/smtpd[4171]: 5A1831C1B22: client=unknown[90.164.39.14], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=[username]@eddelus.com
Jul 23 15:47:56 eddelus postfix/cleanup[4210]: 5A1831C1B22: message-id=<7a7a5ee4-d319-b649-7896-851d498e4aff@eddelus.com>
Jul 23 15:47:56 eddelus postfix/qmgr[3798]: 5A1831C1B22: from=<[username]@eddelus.com>, size=640, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 23 15:47:56 eddelus postfix/error[4211]: 5A1831C1B22: to=<[reciever]@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.27, delays=0.25/0.02/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Jul 23 15:47:56 eddelus postfix/submission/smtpd[4171]: disconnect from unknown[90.164.39.14] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
```

EDIT:

[List of ports enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncZnu.png)

[Scaleway allow smtp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk5U4.png)

Comment: Did you reboot the server after removing the SMTP block?

Comment: Yes, restart the server but still fail

Comment: Can you connect to other mail servers on port 25 or do all of them time out?

Comment: I've tried it with gmail, outlook and another server that I have but all fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log contains:

```
connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.26]:25: Connection timed out
```

The connection is blocked somewhere, possibly by a firewall. Either by yours of the firewall of your provider. In case of the later contact your provider to get the port opened.

You can test the connectivity with `netcat -v 74.125.68.26 25`. You should see *"connection succeeded"*. Otherwise something is blocking. Without more information, I can't help more :/ – sebix 18 hours ago

Comment: I have port 25 enabled :D

Comment: In all devices including those installed by the provider? Where is this server located?

Comment: I think, The server is hosted in scaleway, I requested the opening of these ports and they are enabled, I also registered the port with the command ufw allow 25. I do not know if I leave anything

Comment: You can test the connectivity with `netcat -v 74.125.68.26 25`. You should see "connection succeeded". Otherwise something is blocking. Without more information, I can't help more :/

Comment: Returns: sc-in-f26.1e100.net [74.125.68.26] 25 (smtp): Connection timed out
But I can connect by telnet from my local pc. I do not know what else I can give you. any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I created a new security group and added the server. It seems that everything works correctly, thank you very much for everything!

Comment: Great, so it was the firewall or something similar? ;)

Comment: Yes, I understand that something happened in the process of unlocking the default group and did not perform correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
[74.125.68.26]:25: Connection timed out
```

You weren't able to connect recipients MTA (Gmail) on port `25`. This usually means that SMTP port `25` is blocked on some level.

- What kind of Internet connection you have? Sometimes ISPs block SMTP to fight spam, if the connection is not meant for email servers. You could contact your ISP and ask if they could open the port. It's also possible that you'd need to deliver all outgoing mail through ISP's SMTP server.
- Check your firewall.

Submission works, because it uses separate port.

Comment: Scaleway controls the servers, I requested access to these ports. They should not be blocking the output of emails.
The firewall is correctly configured, launch the command ufw allow 25, and I can connect using telnet